# I am unable to upload image in MySQLi using ajax in CodeIgniter

Tags: file-upload, jquery-file-upload

Why my code does not work and it does not upload image in mysqli db using ajax in codeigniter?

When I click on upload , it does not say anything and image does not upload.

Here is view form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="title"/>

                    </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" placeholder="title"/>
                        
                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_upload">Upload</button>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    

                </form>
```

In view file here is ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({

            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>img_controller/do_upload',
            type: 'post',
            data: new formData(this),
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(data){
                alert("image has been uploaded.")
            }

        });

    });
  </script>
```

Controller Code:

```
<?Php


defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class img_controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $admin=$this->session->userdata('admin');
            
            $this->load->model('upload_model');

            if(empty($admin)){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Your session has been expired.');
                redirect(base_url().'admin/login/index');

            }
        }

public function index(){

    $this->load->view('img_view');

}

public function do_upload(){
$config['upload_path'] = '.\Public\Uploads';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|png|jpg';
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload',$config);

if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
    $data = array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());

    $title = $this->input->post('title');
    $image = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
    $result = $this->uplod_model->save_upload($title,$image);
    echo json_encode($result);

}


}


    
}

?>
```

Finally Model Code:

```
<?php
class upload_model extends CI_Model{

    function save_upload($title,$image){
        $data = array('title' =>$title,'file_name'=>$image);

        $result = $this->db->insert('image_db',$data);
        return $result;
            }
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your server logs? If so, what error did you find? Did you look at the actual request using Dev Tools -> Network? If so, what did it say? Was it responding? Was there an error?